# discrepancies between diff.equ. for SIR model of infection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading [this book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-78911-6) as background for thesis research, and I'm confused by the explanation of the SIR model given in the first chapter.

On p. 7, I'm given
$$\frac{dS}{dt} = −\beta SI$$
and
$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \beta SI - \gamma I$$

where S is the number of susceptibles and I is the number of infectious people. $S + I + R = N$ is the total population size. It says "Here, the transmission rate (per capita) is β and the recovery rate is γ (so the mean infectious period is 1/γ)."

Taking the ratio of the above two, they give
$$\frac{dI}{dS} = -1 + \frac{1}{\mathcal{R}_0S}$$
where $\mathcal{R}_0S = \frac{\beta N}{\gamma}$,
but I get
$$\frac{dI}{dS} = -1 + \frac{N}{\mathcal{R}_0S}$$
which is what is in a later chapter (by a different author). Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: In this model, S+I is not constant hence I *hope* they did not write S+I = N with N constant.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been S+I+R=N. My typo! I've corrected it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's actually a matter of how the author defines $\mathcal R_0$. I have always seen it defined as a dimensionless quantity (does not depend on population size), given as the product of the transmission rate, $\beta$, and the mean infectious period, $1/\gamma$. This is so that the basic reproduction number can be compared between epidemics having different population sizes (that, and dimensionless quantities are nice to work with). So, taking $\mathcal R_0 = \beta/\gamma$, I get

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}S} = \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}S}{\mathrm{d}t}} = \frac{\beta S I - \gamma I}{-\beta SI} = -1 + \frac{\gamma}{\beta S} = -1 + \frac{1}{\mathcal R_0 S}$$

**Note:** I have typically used $\mathcal{R}_0$ instead of $\mathbb R_0$ to represent the basic reproduction number to avoid any possible confusion with the common notation $\mathbb R$ representing the real numbers.

Comment: But isn't $\mathcal{R}_0$ supposed to be the number of secondary cases produced by an index case in an otherwise completely susceptible population? So it would have to depend on the population size, right?